# Simple Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am Making the **Chatting application**

which require to send **push notification** in android.

I really don't have any idea about it because I am very new in Android.

So **how can I get push notification when I receive message from other User of application**.

Please make it **as simple as possible**.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Ofcorse but it require Server URL in those sample. but I dont want to call that Is it possible to use push notification without using Server URL.

Comment: Ok do you have any simple application when user click on button it shows push notification. Something like that

Answer (score 2):

you will get all info here

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

and here is example

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

this will help you..

Comment: I already visit it but it were so complex and I havnt any PHP code it all will handle from admin side. So please send me simple code.

Comment: @NiravDabhi if you are not using PHP, what technology you are using to store the chat data and backend support for the same?

Comment: I use php. but my admin says for push notification it will not require to call Server_url. It will only need sender key and device id which will generate Registration key And I need to use registration key further. Can you tell me how it will be possible?

Comment: No that is not correct getting regration id is the first step in GCM   you can get registration by  GoogleCloudMessaging gcm  = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
          if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

Comment: take look @ this for both client side and server side are given here      http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/